# Is there a way to apply multiple CSS position properties to an HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I need a header 1 element that stays fixed at the top of the screen and has a relative position.
Here are the HTML elements:

```
<h1 class="sticky">Text goes here</h1>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.sticky {
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    /* I know I cannot add multiple */
    /* position properties, so my */
    /* question really is what should */
    /* I do from here? */
}
```

For some reason, that doesn't seem to work. I either use sticky, or relative.
Is there a fix for this?

Comment: An element can only have one position - anything more doesn't make sense - ans As you already know (I assume), the second `position` simply overrides the first. What is the purpose of trying to do this? If you explain what you are trying to do, we might be able to help!

Comment: Well I basically need the h1 element to stay centered while maintaining a fixed position. Is this possible?

Comment: @FluffyKitten OP already knows about this as per the comment in CSS.

Comment: How about wrapping your h1 with a span and give it the class sticky then make new class for your h1 and give it position relative that should work

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, and I acknowledged that in my comment.

Comment: @AhmadDalao I'll try that and see if it works. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @AhmadDalao Yes it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: @AhmadDalao there is no need for adding extra elements - it's simply a matter of making the sticky div take up the full with of the screen.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Agree with you! There is no need to for `span` element as long as if thats what OP is after.

Comment: @FluffyKitten ya that works too.

Answer (score 0):

The text *is* being centred... the problem is that using `position:fixed` makes the div the same width as the text, so there is no extra space around it so it doesn't *appear* to be centred.

All you need to do is make the div the full width of the screen, then the text will be centred across the full width rather than in a smaller container.

```
.sticky {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    /* rest of your CSS here... */
}
```

You can see it in this Working Snippet:

```css
.sticky {
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sticky">Text goes here</h1>
```